# How to insert integer or decimal number into openxml cell

Tags: c#, openxml

```
Cell cellName = new Cell();
cellName.DataType = CellValues.Number;
cellName.CellValue = new CellValue(10);
//error i'm getting here: "cannot convert int to string"
newRow.AppendChild(cellName);
```

Here I'm getting error

> cannot convert int to string

If I'm converting same value to `string` then in Excel file I'm getting Suggestion Like 2nd screenshot. Guys Please help me out in this.

Comment: From Review: What C# library are you using? Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51647043/edit) your question and provide more details. Avoid posting comments to your own question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`CellValue` has two constructor one is default another is parameterize `CellValue(String)`. So you need to convert your parameter to `string` value.

```
int number = 90;
CellValue cl = new CellValue(Convert.ToString(number));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using following code

```
 Cell cellName = new Cell();
 cellName.DataType = CellValues.Number;

 //you can get or set more porperties with this object
 CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();

 //If you want to set text as number 
 cellValue.Text = Convert.ToString(10);

 //If you want to set text as boolean 
 cellValue.Text = Convert.ToString(true);

 //If you want to set text as decimal 
 cellValue.Text = Convert.ToString(123.45M);

 cellName.CellValue = cellValue;
```

`cellValue.Text` property gives you to gets or sets the text of the current element.

You just need to change your datatype to string

Comment: @Arkesh Kumar, view updated solution might be it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cellName.CellValue = new CellValue(10); //error i am getting here "cannot convert int to string"
```

10 is an integer, while the constructor needs a string.
Manually, you can do it like this.

```
cellName.CellValue = new CellValue("10");
```

Otherwise, if you have a variable, do this:

```
int number = 20;
cellName.CellValue = new CellValue(number.ToString());
```

Comment: But after doing this Excel will show one suggestion like you saved number as text.